# SHA-256 Hashing Functionality

Tags: sha-256

It seems all these options are correct to me

> - fingerprint of the provided input.
> - A one-way deterministic hash function.
> - symmetric hash function
> - A hash function that generates a digest.

Anyone identify the wrong option and why?

Comment: The first is a shortcut for the last, and is arguably incorrect since "a hash" can be understood as the value output by the hash function, rather than the function.

Comment: Related for the definition of symmetric and asymmetric hash functions [Difference between symmetric and asymmetric hash function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5861/18298)

Comment: Appologies have amended my question. There was an error

Answer (score 2):

1. "A has that generates digest" seems wrong because a hash can not do much. You need a function to make something.
2. "A one-way deterministic hash function" is correct. In theoretic computer engineering, it is not known whether "one-way"-functions really exist. But in common sense hash is called a "one-way"-function. And they are deterministic. For the same input, you get the same output.
3. "symmetric hash function" is correct. Hash algorithms are part of symmetric cryptography.
4. "a hash function that generates a digest" is correct. See 1.

Comment: the 3. option is not totally correct. See my comment under the question.

Comment: Amended my question, 1st option,had an error